# Tylenol problem

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series

For quite some time I whenever I am taking a Tylenol, often I take half a caplet, and put the other half back in the bottle. Next time again I take a caplet, break it in half and put the other half in the bottle. Now many times when I pick another caplet, it is a whole caplet I am getting, putting half back in the bottle. So the number of "wholes" are getting less and the number of "halves" are getting more. I have been wondering: How many caplets should I pick this way, until I pick a half caplet? In other words, what is the expected number of whole caplets I have to take before I pick my first half caplet? I realized that with 100 caplets, this computation is getting out of control, so I tried to look at this problem with only 20 whole caplets to begin with. So on the first draw, you don't get a half caplet: $1(0/20)$. Then if the first is a whole ($20/20$) and the second is the (only) half caplet: $(20/20)(1/20)$ times $2$ because you did $2$ draws. If the third draw is a half caplet: $(20/20)(19/20)(2/20)$ times $3$. (There are now $2$ half caplets in the bottle). So expectation: $$E(X)=1(0/20)+2(20/20)(1/20)+3(20/20)(19/20)(2/20)+4(20/20)(19/20)(18/20)(3/20)+5(20/20)(19/20)(18/20)(17/20)(4/20)+...$$ I did this work in my TI and arrived at 6.29 (rounded) and so according to the expectation, you can expect the 6th draw (or so) to be a half caplet. My question is now: Using sequences/series (or some other method), how can the expectation be converted into some algebra problem, instead of having to type it up in the TI?

Comment: It seems to be $\frac{n!}{n^n} \sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{n^k}{k!}$, i.e. [OEIS A063170](https://oeis.org/A063170) divided by $n^n$.  This is related to "Schenker sums"

Comment: @Henry. Hmm, I knew it wouldn't be straight forward. Thanks for the link

Comment: The series is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{19! \cdot (k+2)}{(19-k)!\cdot 20^{k+1}}$

Comment: Alternatively $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{19}{k}\cdot k\cdot \frac{ (k+2)}{ 20^{k+1}}$

Comment: Why does $k$ go to infinity?

Comment: This was a  wrong notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e(w,h)$ be the expected number of draws needed to get a half caplet when the bottle contains $w$ whole and $h$ half caplets.  We want to compute $e(w,0)$.  By conditioning on the first draw, we obtain
$$
e(w,h)=
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if $w=0$}\\
1 + \frac{w}{w+h}e(w-1,h+1) + \frac{h}{w+h}\cdot 0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Hence 
\begin{align}
e(w,0)
&=1+\frac{w}{w}e(w-1,1)\\
&=1+\left(1+\frac{w-1}{w}e(w-2,2)\right)\\
&=1+1+\frac{w-1}{w}e(w-2,2)\\
&=1+1+\frac{w-1}{w}\left(1+\frac{w-2}{w}e(w-3,3)\right)\\
&=1+1+\frac{w-1}{w}+\frac{w-1}{w}\cdot\frac{w-2}{w}e(w-3,3)\\
&\dots\\
&=1+1+\frac{w-1}{w}+\frac{w-1}{w}\cdot\frac{w-2}{w}+\dots+\prod_{j=0}^{w-1}\frac{w-j}{w}e(0,w)\\
&=1+\sum_{k=0}^{w-1}\prod_{j=0}^k\frac{w-j}{w}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=0}^{w-1}\frac{1}{w^{k+1}}\prod_{j=0}^k (w-j)\\
&=1+\sum_{k=0}^{w-1}\frac{1}{w^{k+1}}\cdot\frac{w!}{(w-k-1)!}\\
&=1+\sum_{j=0}^{w-1}\frac{w!}{w^{w-j}j!}\\
&=1+\frac{w!}{w^w}\sum_{j=0}^{w-1}\frac{w^j}{j!}\\
&=\frac{w!}{w^w}\sum_{j=0}^w\frac{w^j}{j!}
\end{align}

Comment: I did not see this one coming. I knew it would be "straight forward" since there is an increasing number of fractions in the expectation. Not suitable to share with my students unfortunately

Comment: I just found this: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.121.04.299

Comment: The linked paper by Velleman shows that the sum is asymptotic to $1+\sqrt{\pi w/2}$.